# How to formulate an ADMM optimization problem involving inequality constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

I have an optimization problem as shown below:

$\begin{alignat}{2}
 &\!\min_{x}      &\qquad & J(x) \\
 &\text{subject to}  &       & t_{1} = x_{11}C_{11}+ x_{12}C_{21},\\
 &     &       & t_{1} > 0,\\
 &                   &       & t_{2} = x_{21}C_{21}+ x_{22}C_{22},\\
 &     &       & t_{2} > 0\\
\end{alignat}$

Here, $J(x)$ is a convex function depending on the set of variables $x = \lbrace x_{11},~x_{12},~x_{21},~x_{22} \rbrace$. The entities $C_{11},~C_{12},~C_{21}$ and $ C_{22}$ are the constants belonging to the set of Real numbers. I want to solve the above optimization problem using the ADMM approach. But, the literature that I have referred to, has not given a clear method to reformulate an optimization problem shown above to the ADMM compatible form.

However, the slide 10 in the presentation [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/lectures/23-dual-meth.pdf), has formulated an optimization problem with inequality constraints in the Dual decomposition form, but I require the ADMM formulation of the similar problem involving inequalities. Also, they are $\leq$ inequalities, while the optimization problem stated above has strict $>$ inequalities. Hence, I request an approach or some good literature from the community to deal with this kind of inequalities while formulating ADMM optimization problem.

Please note that I am a beginner in this field, and have a very little knowledge about it. So an approach with detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the paper [Distributed Convex Optimization with Many Non-Linear
Constraints](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02967.pdf), I found the answer to my question. In the section 6, the authors clearly explains the approach they took to transform an optimization problem involving inequalities into the ADMM form. I would strongly recommend reading the whole paper to get a better understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformulate any > inequality as a < inequality by reversing the left-hand and right-hand sides. For instance, $t_1 > 0$ is equivalent to $-t_1 < 0$.

Note that practical solvers generally don't make a distinction between < and $\le$. So the solver will solve something like $-t_1 \le 0$.  If you need $t_1$ to be strictly greater than 0, then you will need to pick some suitable small number, large enough to absorb solver tolerance in satisfying the inequality, and specify $-t_1 \le$ small_number

Comment: Thanks for the response, I afterwards realized that this was a trivial task. I have edited my question little bit to make it more clear that, I actually need the approach to formulate the optimization problems involving inequalities into ADMM compatible form.